# Hibernate example with multiple 1 to many mappings needed

Tags: java, hibernate

Been looking all over and can't find an example of this.. I am new to Hibernate but can create a single level JSON...  I can make this happen if I use prepared statements and multiple arrays, but I can't get it to work using Hibernate and createSQLQuery.

I need to create JSON with multiple 1 to many levels, ie:

{
      "success": true,
      "count": 1,
      "message": "",
      "data": [

{
                  "inProgress" : false,
                  "item" : "372",
                  "Time" : "09:00",
                  "Date" : "2013-03-22",
                  "status" : "inProgress",

"labels" : [
                        "first",
                        "second",
                        "third",
                        “last”
                  ],

"item" : [
                        {
                              "rank" : "1st",
                              “time”: “6:36:05”,

"details" : [
                                    {
                                          "interval" : "1:31.63"
                                    },

{
                                          "interval" : "1:32.63"
                                    },

{
                                          "interval" : "1:35.99"
                                    },

{
                                          "interval" : "1:38.63"
                                    }
                              ]
                        }
                  ]
            }
      ]
}

So there can be multiple details in multiple items and there are multiple labels.

```
            Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql)
                    .addScalar("item",Hibernate.STRING)
                    .addScalar("time",Hibernate.STRING)
                    .addScalar("date",Hibernate.STRING)
                .addScalar("futureProgression",Hibernate.STRING) 
            .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ABC.class));

            resultList = query.list();
```

I can create the top level, but I can't figure out how to use .addEntity to insert entities into that level...

Anyone have an example handy?

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: You would like to convert a list of objects returned by hibernate query into JSON?

Comment: Why do you want entities in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Go through the below link to see how to define 1-to-many relationship with mappings

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/example-parentchild.html

If you persist top level object with a set of lower level objects, hibernate will take care of creation of top level and lower level entries in the table.

session.save(parent)

Answer (score 0):

listen if you are using `query.createSQLQuery(String sql)` when invoking `query.list()` it will return a list each list element got Object Array [ Row from database in anther language ].

if you like to work with JSON from hibernate there is a sample :

```
import org.json.*;
//.... your imports here :
//

public class JSONObjectRetriever{

    public JSONObject getDataByID(){
        ArrayList<Object[]> resultList = HibernateManager.getItems();
        ArrayList<Item> finalJsonList = new ArrayList<Item>();

        if(resultList != null)
        {
           Iterator<Object[]> it = resultList.iterator();
           while(it.hasNext())
           {
               Object [] obj = it.next(); // fetching one row from the database.

               //---- Deprecated ...
               //finalJsonList.add(obj[0]);
               //finalJsonList.add(obj[1]);
               //finalJsonList.add(obj[2]);

               //---- the new fragment is : How Add Label to the values :
               //------------------------------------

               finalJsonList.put("Item ID", obj[1]);
               finalJsonList.put("Item Name", obj[2]);
               finalJsonList.put("Item Price", obj[3]);

           }
           JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(catList);
       HashMap<String, JSONArray> map = new HashMap<String, JSONArray>();

       map.put("finalJsonList", jsonArray);
       JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(map);
       return jsonObject;
        }
        else{
           return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the Hibernate Manager will be like this :

```
public class HibernateManager{

   private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
   static{
       //initialize the session factory here.....
   }

   public static List getItems(){
     String sql = "...."; // put your sql here full String;
     Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
     session.beginTransaction();
     Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
     List resultList = query.list();
     session.getTransaction().commit();
     return resultList;
   }
}
```

Then you need Servlet and define The response type is application/json
inside this servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    JSONObjectsRetriever jR = new JSONObjectsRetriever();
    JSONObject jsonObj = jR.getDataByID();

    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setContentType("application/json");

    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    //System.out.println(jsonObj);
    writer.print(jsonObj);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```

then in you ajax skills or jQuery you can use this servlet in callback method to extact the values as you wish : in this sample i used jquery ....

```
$.ajax(
{
      url : CONTEXT_ROOT+"ItemsJSONFromHibernateServlet",
  type : "GET",
  dataType : "json",
      data : {"param1": value, "param2" : value2, ... etc}, //if you are like to send parameters to the database
  success: function(data){
         // this will return JSON Object do what do you like here ...

         //Iterating through JSON will be like this :

        for (var key in data) 
        {
          if (data.hasOwnProperty(key))
          {
        //alert(key + " -> " + data[key]);
        var subData = data[key];
        //alert(subData.ID+"Before");
        for(var j=0; j < subData.length; j++)
            {
       //alert(subData[j].Key);
       if(subData[j].Key == val)
               {
         alert(subData[j].Value);
         break;
           }
             }
       }
    }
      },
      error: function(jqHXR){
         // to handle errors
      }
});
```

i hope this help .....

~Ahmad A. Taha

Comment: Thanks - but I don't see how this will create anything more than just the flat JSON..  Would I need to add another iterator/while loop within the first to create the "labels" list??

Comment: I Edited the code above that how to add Lables for each object

Comment: and i added in javascript $.ajax() sample how to iterate through json result from jQuery callback function